# Delete multiple files matching a pattern

Tags: python

I have made an online gallery using Python and Django. I've just started to add editing functionality, starting with a rotation. I use sorl.thumbnail to auto-generate thumbnails on demand.

When I edit the original file, I need to clean up all the thumbnails so new ones are generated. There are three or four of them per image (I have different ones for different occasions).

I *could* hard-code in the file-varients... But that's messy and if I change the way I do things, I'll need to revisit the code.

Ideally I'd like to do a regex-delete. In regex terms, all my originals are named like so:

```
^(?P<photo_id>\d+)\.jpg$
```

So I want to delete:

```
^(?P<photo_id>\d+)[^\d].*jpg$
```

(Where I replace `photo_id` with the ID I want to clean.)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import os, re

def purge(dir, pattern):
    for f in os.listdir(dir):
        if re.search(pattern, f):
            os.remove(os.path.join(dir, f))
```

Then you would pass the directory containing the files and the pattern you wish to match.

Comment: I'd be tempted to compile the regex before entering into the loop... But yeah, that looks good.

Comment: it's ok to use `glob.glob` instead of this.

Answer (score 140):

Using the glob module:

```
import glob, os
for f in glob.glob("P*.jpg"):
    os.remove(f)
```

Alternatively, using pathlib:

```
from pathlib import Path
for p in Path(".").glob("P*.jpg"):
    p.unlink()
```

Comment: os.remove gives me a system error (windows) so I used shutil.rmtree instead.

Comment: @sparrow The question was how to delete *files* matching a pattern, not to delete whole directory trees matching a pattern.

Answer (score 14):

If you need recursion into several subdirectories, you can use this method:

```
import os, re, os.path
pattern = "^(?P<photo_id>\d+)[^\d].*jpg$"
mypath = "Photos"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(mypath):
    for file in filter(lambda x: re.match(pattern, x), files):
        os.remove(os.path.join(root, file))
```

You can safely remove subdirectories on the fly from `dirs`, which contains the list of the subdirectories to visit at each node.

Note that if you are in a directory, you can also get files corresponding to a simple pattern expression with `glob.glob(pattern)`. In this case you would have to substract the set of files to keep from the whole set, so the code above is more efficient.

Answer (score 10):

How about this?

```
import glob, os, multiprocessing
p = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
p.map(os.remove, glob.glob("P*.jpg"))
```

Mind you this does not do recursion and uses wildcards (not regex).

**UPDATE**
In Python 3 the `map()` function will return an *iterator*, not a list. This is useful since you will probably want to do some kind processing on the items anyway, and an iterator will always be more memory-efficient to that end.

If however, a list is what you *really* need, just do this:

```
...
list(p.map(os.remove, glob.glob("P*.jpg")))
```

I agree it's not the most functional way, but it's concise and does the job.

Comment: map() is intended to transform a set of values, rather than run an arbitrary command on them. Therefore this is not the most recommended technique, and actually fails in Python 3 as map() now returns an iterable, rather than immediately evaluating the functions.

Comment: Please note that map returns a generator as of python 3 and this will *not* execute the function remove.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear to me that you actually want to do any named-group matching -- in the use you describe, the photoid is an *input* to the deletion function, and named groups' purpose is "output", i.e., extracting certain substrings from the matched string (and accessing them by name in the match object).  So, I would recommend a simpler approach:

```
import re
import os

def delete_thumbnails(photoid, photodirroot):
  matcher = re.compile(r'^%s\d+\D.*jpg$' % photoid)
  numdeleted = 0
  for rootdir, subdirs, filenames in os.walk(photodirroot):
    for name in filenames:
      if not matcher.match(name):
        continue
      path = os.path.join(rootdir, name)
      os.remove(path)
      numdeleted += 1
  return "Deleted %d thumbnails for %r" % (numdeleted, photoid)
```

You can pass the photoid as a normal string, or as a RE pattern piece if you need to remove several matchable IDs at once (e.g., `r'abc[def]` to remove abcd, abce, and abcf in a single call) -- that's the reason I'm inserting it literally in the RE pattern, rather than inserting the string `re.escape(photoid)` as would be normal practice.  Certain parts such as counting the number of deletions and returning an informative message at the end are obviously frills which you should remove if they give you no added value in your use case.

Others, such as the "if not ... // continue" pattern, are highly recommended practice in Python (flat is better than nested: bailing out to the next leg of the loop as soon as you determine there is nothing to do on this one is better than nesting the actions to be done within an `if`), although of course other arrangements of the code would work too.

Answer (score 2):

My recomendation:

```
def purge(dir, pattern, inclusive=True):
    regexObj = re.compile(pattern)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir, topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, name)
            if bool(regexObj.search(path)) == bool(inclusive):
                os.remove(path)
        for name in dirs:
            path = os.path.join(root, name)
            if len(os.listdir(path)) == 0:
                os.rmdir(path)
```

This will recursively remove every file that matches the pattern by default, and every file that doesn't if inclusive is true.  It will then remove any empty folders from the directory tree.

Comment: Please correct the description for `inclusive`. I would also better not match the whole path with the pattern but only the file name, because when the pattern is elsewhere in the path, you will unintentionally delete everything. Also a remark would be helpful that the pattern language is that of `re` and not that of e.g. `bash`. I will suggest a respective edit. It is a matter of taste if you remove empty directories that way, because it will also delete empty directories that have been empty even before the pattern `rm`, i.e. usually unintentional deletes.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os, sys, glob, re

def main():

    mypath = "<Path to Root Folder to work within>"
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(mypath):
        for file in files:
            p = os.path.join(root, file)
            if os.path.isfile(p):
                if p[-4:] == ".jpg": #Or any pattern you want
                os.remove(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def recursive_purge(dir, pattern):
    for f in os.listdir(dir):
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir, f)):
            recursive_purge(os.path.join(dir, f), pattern)
        elif re.search(pattern, os.path.join(dir, f)):
            os.remove(os.path.join(dir, f))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

I find `Popen(["rm " + file_name + "*.ext"], shell=True, stdout=PIPE).communicate()` to be a much simpler solution to this problem. Although this is prone to injection attacks, I don't see any issues if your program is using this internally.