# Delete all files with partial filename python

Tags: python, regex

I have files in my present working directory that I would like to delete. They all have a filename that starts with the string 'words' (for example, files `words_1.csv` and `words_2.csv`). I want to match all files in the current directory that start with 'words' and delete them. What would the search pattern be?

I found this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548704/delete-multiple-files-matching-a-pattern), but it doesn't quite answer the question.

```
import os, re

def purge(dir, pattern):
    for f in os.listdir(dir):
        if re.search(pattern, f):
            os.remove(os.path.join(dir, f))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you have this function and you are asking how it may be used. You should be able to call simply:

```
purge('/path/to/your/dir','words.*')
```

This will remove any files starting with the string "words".

Comment: Not quite: any file name starting with "words" and having a "csv" extension.  You've deleted any words.* file.  This misses the two cited instances, and deletes other files, such as "words.txt".

Comment: How does this miss words_1.csv? It's also not clear that all files are csv files, those are simply the two examples provided.

Comment: This works only if I replace 'words.*' with 'words*' Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
t = 'words_1.csv'
print(t.startswith('words'))
```

it‘s done.
and the pattern may be the `'^words.*\.csv$'`,but i suggest you read [python RE doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: To be safe, include a `os.path.isfile(filename)` as a directory could also start with `words`.

Comment: This requires me to list each file name, doesn't it? I want to find all files in the directory that start with 'words' and delete them.

Answer (score 0):

**pattern** is a regular expression pattern.  In your case, it's simply anything beginning with "words" and ending with ".csv", so you can use

```
pattern = "words*.csv"
```

Comment: You seem to have written a glob instead of a regex.