# Remove all files in a directory matching regular expression in Python

Tags: python

I have two files in the directory home/documents/ named 2018-06-rs.csv000 and 2018-06-rs.csv001. I want to remove both the files from the directory.

Following is my code:

```
import datetime
import os

now = datetime.datetime.now()
file_date = now.strftime("%Y-%m")

os.remove("/home/documents/"+file_date+"-rs.csv*")
```

The error I'm getting is :

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/documents/201806-rs.csv*'
```

Listing the above path directs to the actual file though.

```
ls /home/documents/201806-rs.csv*
```

Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete multiple files matching a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548704/delete-multiple-files-matching-a-pattern)

Comment: The linked question has some good approaches to the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import os, re

def purge(dir, pattern):
    for f in os.listdir(dir):
        if re.search(pattern, f):
            os.remove(os.path.join(dir, f))
```

Make sure `dir` is the correct path to the directory that contains your files, and `pattern` is a valid regex.

Comment: Thanks Jianan.

def remove_files_by_pattern(dir, pattern):
    for f in os.listdir(dir):
        if re.search(pattern, f):
            os.remove(os.path.join(dir, f))

dir = '/home/documents/'
pattern = file_date+'-rs.csv'+'*'

purge(dir,pattern)

The above code gives me invalid syntax error.

Comment: Without the proper code formatting, I cannot really say what is wrong with your code syntax. Besides, your `pattern` variable is not correct. Saying you have a `date` as `2018-06-20`, your `pattern` after concatenation will be `2018-06-20-rs.csv*`. I don't think this is what you expected.