# Deleting files of specific extension using * in Python

Tags: python, file, delete-file

I have couple of text files named as:

```
temp1.txt
temp2.txt
temp3.txt
temp4.txt
track.txt
```

I want to delete files only starting with `temp` and ending with `.txt`.
I tried using `os.remove("temp*.txt")` but I'm getting error as:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'temp*.txt'
```

What is the right way to do this using python 3.7?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548704/delete-multiple-files-matching-a-pattern

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete multiple files matching a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548704/delete-multiple-files-matching-a-pattern)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path

for filename in Path(".").glob("temp*.txt"):
    filename.unlink()
```

Comment: is there any way we can do this by ```os.remove()``` ?

Comment: Yes. `os.remove(filename)` will work here also. The `filename` is a `Path` object. 
 `Path.unlink()` does the same as `os.unlink(pathname)` which is identical to `os.remove(pathname)`.

Comment: Can you please explain what have you done in this command: ```Path(".").glob("temp*.txt")``` ?

Answer (score 1):

This pattern matching can be done by using **glob** module. And pathlib is one more alterantive if you don't want to use os.path module

```
import os 
import glob
path = os.path.join("/home", "mint", "Desktop", "test1") # If you want to manually specify path
print(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))   # To get the path of current directory 
print(os.listdir(path)) # To verify the list of files present in the directory 
required_files = glob.glob(path+"/temp*.txt") # This gives all the files that matches the pattern
print("required_files are ", required_files)
results = [os.remove(x) for x in required_files]
print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your question, you can take a look at the methods of built-in function [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str). Just check what the filename starts and ends with like:

```
>>> name = "temp1.txt"
>>> name.startswith("temp") and name.endswith("txt")
True
```

Then you can use a `for` loop with `os.remove()`:

```
for name in files_list:
    if name.startswith("temp") and name.endswith("txt"):
        os.remove(name)
```

Use `os.listdir()` or `str.split()` to create the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob


# get a recursive list of file paths that matches pattern  
fileList = glob.glob('temp*.txt', recursive=True)    
# iterate over the list of filepaths & remove each file. 

for filePath in fileList:
    try:
        os.remove(filePath)
    except OSError:
        print("Error while deleting file")
```